# I'm trying to place a bed frame above a UK stair box (do not want the weight on top of the box)

Tags: walls, screws, bedroom, bed

So I have this insanely large stair box in my room (very small room) and I want to place a bedframe above it so that it saves space within the room.

I have no idea how to draw and upload a succinct diagram so will try my best to describe the area. The box is in the right hand corner of the room as you enter. The two walls are the wall with the door (right hand side) and the wall that is barren (left hand side).

I do not wish the weight of the frame to be placed upon the box so what I thought of doing was drilling into the brick walls at least 2-3 inches and attaching the frame. Then having the frame come outwards and the remainder of the weight to be supported by poles that touch the flooring of the room (this can be poles or just large sections of joined wood like the IKEA bookcases in terms of how it looks?)

I hope that this makes some sense; two sides of the frame into the wall, other two sides into the larger frame bookshelf like touching ground.

I want to know if this would be feasible and if so things that I should consider.
(I will try my best to research how to create an image that better describes my dilemma).

Comment: It sounds like a bunk bed setup with the bed on top and storage below.  A google search should give you ideas.

Comment: My understanding is that US OSB strength has the same strength in the UK if thickness matches. Unfortunately I don't know how US lumber species and grade translate to UK standards. I think that your softwood lumber is typically Spruce-Pine-Fir under the US's design taxonomy, but I have no idea how your C16, C24, etc. translate into our Structural Select, #2, etc. If you can translate your available grades and species into US equivalents, then I could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a better keyword to search for: "loft bed".

Student versions are traditionally semi-freestanding, braced against the walls to reduce the need for diagonal bracing but being supported by legs at all four corners. It sounds like you want to anchor to the wall on one side instead; that certainly should be doable if you can drive (enough) strong (enough) anchors to carry the load.

For determining that load I'd say start with the weight of the bed platform and bedding, add the weight of the maximum number of people who might be up there, add whatever dynamic load those people might create in addition to their weight, then assume each side of the bed has to carry at least half that load. Might be good to add a safety factor as well.

Comment: It is good to have a bed that can hold up to a dynamic load.

Comment: It isn't only kids who bounce on beds. Though adults are likely to apply some sideways forces as well.

Comment: Sleeping room floors under the IRC get designed for 30 psf live load. Snow-free roofs get designed for 20 psf live load. I'd start with 30 psf and then persuade myself that I could go closer to 20 psf if the 30 psf design seemed too heavy.